# Convert word_tokenize to sentence

Tags: python, nltk

I am new to Python nltk

Current, I have a program that does word_tokenize from a sentence.  The word_tokenize is then processed that corrects some capitalization to some nouns.  This process works fine, now I want to convert the processed word_tokenize to a sentence again.  I can easily do this by a loop and for every display, I just need to add space.  But there will be cases that this will not work for words like "it's, I'm, don't and etc." because word_tokenize save those words separately.  Doing so my processed word_tokenize will be converted to "it 's, I 'm, don 't and etc."

Is there a function of nltk that does the word_tokenize to sentence perfectly?

Comment: `from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize`

Comment: sent_tokenize  will convert the whole paragraph into sentences.  What I am looking for is to convert list of words (processed word_tokenize in my case) into a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

nltk has TreebankWordDetokenizer which can reconstruct a sentence from a list of tokens:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
tokens = word_tokenize("I'm happy because it's a good book")
print(tokens)
#['I', "'m", 'happy', 'because', 'it', "'s", 'a', 'good', 'book']

from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
reconstructedSentence = TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize(tokens)
print(reconstructedSentence)
#I'm happy because it's a good book
```